# Change "Super" keybinding Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: shortcut-keys

So I want to try using Ulauncher for a while. However, I can't change the launch keybinding to just being the "Super"-key (I prefer it over any other binding)

I've tried unbinding it, but I can't find anything. Tried in the native settings-menu and using dconf..

Do you guys have any suggestions as how to do it?

Best regards
Mikkel

Comment: I was under the impression that 18.10 uses Gnome 3 instead of Unity?

Comment: It does. Ulauncher can be downloaded from https://ulauncher.io/ - To use it you can do a keybinding like "Ctrl + Space", but is messes with my usual workflow. So I want to change that to be "Super" only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [existing issue](https://github.com/Ulauncher/Ulauncher/issues/190) on the Ulauncher GitHub where one of the author says:

> I've just checked, currently it's not possible to use Win key in hotkey.
>
> Apparently it's a reserved in most of the DEs.

Comment: I see. It's apparently a "modifier" and not a key-event in most DE's, that's why.